# Sum every x elements in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector v like:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 46, 6, 3, 5, 67, 2, ..., 9)
```

I want to add the numbers three by three, so I would have the results of adding 1+6+67...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a sequence by the width you want (in this case 3) which will start from 1 to the length of your vector and then sum:

```
#Data
v <- c(1, 2, 46, 6, 3, 5, 67, 2, 9)
#Seq
seqv <- seq(1,length(v),by = 3)
#Sum
sum(v[seqv])
```

Output:

```
[1] 74
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sequence of values by three and use that to index the vector `v` and then sum the result.

```
v <- 10:19
s <- seq(1,9, by=3)
> v
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
> s
[1] 1 4 7
> sum(v[s])
[1] 39
```